# How to use join in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, inner-join

In MySQL, I have two tables.

**tasks**

id

name

**checklist**

id

member_id

tasks_id

In the php page, I create the sql select string, I have a php variable that has a `members_id` value which is the member id of the person logged in. How can I get all the records of the `tasks` table, and add a new column to it called `completed`, and the value is `true` if there exists a record in the `checklist` table that has the `member_id` the same as the members id php variable and it's `tasks_id` value is the same as the `id` of the `tasks` table, and `false` if it doesn't exist?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you have a `tasks_id` reference in the checklist table if there's no corresponding entry in the `tasks` table? This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The tasks table has all the list of tasks, and I want to keep track of peoples tasks being completed or not. So to indicate if a person (with id x) completed task A, then that means there is a record in the checklist table with member_id being x, and tasks_id being A. If they didn't complete it, then no such record will be in the checklist table.

Comment: You need to have a separate members table then to have false values when testing against all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a `left outer join`:

```
select t.*, (cl.id is not null) as IsCompleted
from tasks t left outer join
     checklist cl
     on t.id = cl.taskid and
        cl.memberid = <your member id goes here>
```

The expression `(cl.id is not null)` returns `true` when there is a record in the `checklist` table and `false` otherwise.

Comment: When I tried this, it only gave the records for the current user, where they completed the task (i.e. IsCompleted is only 1). It skipped the ones where they didn't complete it. I want it so that it shows all records of the tasks table and if they didn't complete it, then the IsCompleted value will say 0.

Comment: @omega . . . Oh, that was an error I shouldn't have made.  The `where` clause turned the `left outer join` into an `inner join`.  The solution is to put the condition in the `where` clause (as it is now).